# UITextField context menu (cut, paste, etc) is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The context menu with the standard text actions (cut, paste, copy, look up) is not showing up when I long press or double tap the text field. Instead, both of these actions seem to select the content of the text field and allow me to drag the selection elsewhere.

I am using the following custom `UITextField` subclass:

```swift
class BMTextField: UITextField {

    required init(placeholder: String? = nil, text: String? = nil) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        font = UIFont(name: Fonts.Light, size: 18)
        textColor = Colors.Gray51
        layer.borderColor = Colors.Gray51Transparent.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.cornerRadius = 0

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.text = text
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 0);

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

}
```

Here is how I'm adding it to my superview (using SnapKit):

```swift
lastNameTextField.textContentType = .familyName
lastNameTextField.autocorrectionType = .yes
showingSuperview.addSubview(lastNameTextField)
lastNameTextField.snp.makeConstraints {
    make in
    make.height.equalTo(M.standardControlHeight)
    make.top.equalTo(firstNameTextField.snp.bottom).offset(S.thirtyTwo)
    make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
}
```

I tried creating a brand new project with a text field, and there, everything works smoothly.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The cause may lie elsewhere. Try to make a minimal brand new project with a BMTextField. Also, remember there needs to be something on the clipboard in order for the Paste menu to appear, and there needs to be a selection in order for the Copy menu to appear.

Comment: I tried, it still doesn't work :/